# Heartbeat won't successfully start up resources from a cold boot when a failed node is present

Tags: linux, ubuntu, heartbeat, heartbeat1

I currently have two ubuntu servers running Heartbeat and DRBD. The servers are directly connected with a 1000Mbps crossover cable on eth1 and have access to an IP camera LAN on eth0.

Now, let's say that one node is down and the remaining functional node is booting after having been shut down. The node that is still functioning won't start up heartbeat and provide access to the drbd resource from a cold boot. I have to manually restart heartbeat by `sudo service heartbeat restart` to get everything up and running.

How can I get it to start fine from a cold start, when only one server is present?

Here is the `ha.cf`:

```
debugfile /var/log/ha-debug
logfile /var/log/ha-log
logfacility none

keepalive 2
deadtime 10
warntime 7
initdead 60
ucast eth1 192.168.2.2
ucast eth0 10.1.10.201
node EMserver1
node EMserver2
respawn hacluster /usr/lib/heartbeat/ipfail
ping 10.1.10.22 10.1.10.21 10.1.10.11
auto_failback off
```

Some material from the syslog:

`harc[4604]: 2012/11/27_13:54:49 info: Running /etc/ha.d//rc.d/status status
mach_down[4632]:    2012/11/27_13:54:49 info: /usr/share/heartbeat/mach_down: nice_failback: foreign resources acquired
mach_down[4632]:    2012/11/27_13:54:49 info: mach_down takeover complete for node emserver2.
Nov 27 13:54:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Initial resource acquisition complete (T_RESOURCES(us))
Nov 27 13:54:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: mach_down takeover complete.
IPaddr[4679]:   2012/11/27_13:54:49 INFO:  Resource is stopped
Nov 27 13:54:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4605]: info: Local Resource acquisition completed.
harc[4713]: 2012/11/27_13:54:49 info: Running /etc/ha.d//rc.d/ip-request-resp ip-request-resp
ip-request-resp[4713]:  2012/11/27_13:54:49 received ip-request-resp IPaddr::10.1.10.254 OK yes
ResourceManager[4732]:  2012/11/27_13:54:50 info: Acquiring resource group: emserver1 IPaddr::10.1.10.254 drbddisk::r0 Filesystem::/dev/drbd1::/shr::ext4 nfs-kernel-server
IPaddr[4759]:   2012/11/27_13:54:50 INFO:  Resource is stopped
ResourceManager[4732]:  2012/11/27_13:54:50 info: Running /etc/ha.d/resource.d/IPaddr 10.1.10.254 start
IPaddr[4816]:   2012/11/27_13:54:50 INFO: Using calculated nic for 10.1.10.254: eth0
IPaddr[4816]:   2012/11/27_13:54:50 INFO: Using calculated netmask for 10.1.10.254: 255.255.255.0
IPaddr[4816]:   2012/11/27_13:54:50 INFO: eval ifconfig eth0:0 10.1.10.254 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.1.10.255
IPaddr[4804]:   2012/11/27_13:54:50 INFO:  Success
ResourceManager[4732]:  2012/11/27_13:54:50 info: Running /etc/ha.d/resource.d/drbddisk r0 start
Filesystem[4965]:   2012/11/27_13:54:50 INFO:  Resource is stopped
ResourceManager[4732]:  2012/11/27_13:54:50 info: Running /etc/ha.d/resource.d/Filesystem /dev/drbd1 /shr ext4 start
Filesystem[5039]:   2012/11/27_13:54:50 INFO: Running start for /dev/drbd1 on /shr
Filesystem[5033]:   2012/11/27_13:54:51 INFO:  Success
ResourceManager[4732]:  2012/11/27_13:54:51 info: Running /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server  start
Nov 27 13:55:00 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Local Resource acquisition completed. (none)
Nov 27 13:55:00 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: local resource transition completed.
Nov 27 13:57:46 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Heartbeat shutdown in progress. (4586)
Nov 27 13:57:46 EMserver1 heartbeat: [5286]: info: Giving up all HA resources.
ResourceManager[5301]:  2012/11/27_13:57:46 info: Releasing resource group: emserver1 IPaddr::10.1.10.254 drbddisk::r0 Filesystem::/dev/drbd1::/shr::ext4 nfs-kernel-server
ResourceManager[5301]:  2012/11/27_13:57:46 info: Running /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server  stop
ResourceManager[5301]:  2012/11/27_13:57:46 info: Running /etc/ha.d/resource.d/Filesystem /dev/drbd1 /shr ext4 stop
Filesystem[5372]:   2012/11/27_13:57:46 INFO: Running stop for /dev/drbd1 on /shr
Filesystem[5372]:   2012/11/27_13:57:47 INFO: Trying to unmount /shr
Filesystem[5372]:   2012/11/27_13:57:47 INFO: unmounted /shr successfully
Filesystem[5366]:   2012/11/27_13:57:47 INFO:  Success
ResourceManager[5301]:  2012/11/27_13:57:47 info: Running /etc/ha.d/resource.d/drbddisk r0 stop
ResourceManager[5301]:  2012/11/27_13:57:47 info: Running /etc/ha.d/resource.d/IPaddr 10.1.10.254 stop
IPaddr[5509]:   2012/11/27_13:57:47 INFO: ifconfig eth0:0 down
IPaddr[5497]:   2012/11/27_13:57:47 INFO:  Success
Nov 27 13:57:47 EMserver1 heartbeat: [5286]: info: All HA resources relinquished.
Nov 27 13:57:48 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing /usr/lib/heartbeat/ipfail process group 4603 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBFIFO process 4589 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBWRITE process 4590 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBREAD process 4591 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBWRITE process 4592 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBREAD process 4593 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBWRITE process 4594 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBREAD process 4595 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBWRITE process 4596 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBREAD process 4597 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBWRITE process 4598 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: killing HBREAD process 4599 with signal 15
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4589 exited. 11 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4596 exited. 10 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4598 exited. 9 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4590 exited. 8 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4595 exited. 7 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4591 exited. 6 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4592 exited. 5 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4593 exited. 4 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4597 exited. 3 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4594 exited. 2 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: Core process 4599 exited. 1 remaining
Nov 27 13:57:49 EMserver1 heartbeat: [4586]: info: emserver1 Heartbeat shutdown complete.`

Here is some more from the log

`ResourceManager[2576]:  2012/11/28_16:32:42 info: Acquiring resource group: emserver1 IPaddr::10.1.10.254 drbddisk::r0 Filesystem::/dev/drbd1::/shr::ext4 nfs-kernel-server
IPaddr[2602]:   2012/11/28_16:32:42 INFO:  Running OK
Filesystem[2653]:   2012/11/28_16:32:43 INFO:  Running OK
Nov 28 16:32:52 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: WARN: node emserver2: is dead
Nov 28 16:32:52 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Dead node emserver2 gave up resources.
Nov 28 16:32:52 EMserver1 ipfail: [1807]: info: Status update: Node emserver2 now has status dead
Nov 28 16:32:52 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Link emserver2:eth1 dead.
Nov 28 16:32:53 EMserver1 ipfail: [1807]: info: NS: We are still alive!
Nov 28 16:32:53 EMserver1 ipfail: [1807]: info: Link Status update: Link emserver2/eth1 now has status dead
Nov 28 16:32:55 EMserver1 ipfail: [1807]: info: Asking other side for ping node count.
Nov 28 16:32:55 EMserver1 ipfail: [1807]: info: Checking remote count of ping nodes.
Nov 28 16:32:57 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Heartbeat shutdown in progress. (1695)
Nov 28 16:32:57 EMserver1 heartbeat: [2734]: info: Giving up all HA resources.
ResourceManager[2751]:  2012/11/28_16:32:57 info: Releasing resource group: emserver1 IPaddr::10.1.10.254 drbddisk::r0 Filesystem::/dev/drbd1::/shr::ext4 nfs-kernel-server
ResourceManager[2751]:  2012/11/28_16:32:57 info: Running /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server  stop
ResourceManager[2751]:  2012/11/28_16:32:57 info: Running /etc/ha.d/resource.d/Filesystem /dev/drbd1 /shr ext4 stop
Filesystem[2829]:   2012/11/28_16:32:57 INFO: Running stop for /dev/drbd1 on /shr
Filesystem[2829]:   2012/11/28_16:32:57 INFO: Trying to unmount /shr
Filesystem[2829]:   2012/11/28_16:32:58 INFO: unmounted /shr successfully
Filesystem[2823]:   2012/11/28_16:32:58 INFO:  Success
ResourceManager[2751]:  2012/11/28_16:32:58 info: Running /etc/ha.d/resource.d/drbddisk r0 stop
ResourceManager[2751]:  2012/11/28_16:32:58 info: Running /etc/ha.d/resource.d/IPaddr 10.1.10.254 stop
IPaddr[2971]:   2012/11/28_16:32:58 INFO: ifconfig eth0:0 down
IPaddr[2958]:   2012/11/28_16:32:58 INFO:  Success
Nov 28 16:32:58 EMserver1 heartbeat: [2734]: info: All HA resources relinquished.
Nov 28 16:32:59 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing /usr/lib/heartbeat/ipfail process group 1807 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBFIFO process 1777 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBWRITE process 1778 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBREAD process 1779 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBWRITE process 1780 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBREAD process 1781 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBWRITE process 1782 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBREAD process 1783 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBWRITE process 1784 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBREAD process 1785 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBWRITE process 1786 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: killing HBREAD process 1787 with signal 15
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1778 exited. 11 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1779 exited. 10 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1780 exited. 9 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1781 exited. 8 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1782 exited. 7 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1783 exited. 6 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1784 exited. 5 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1785 exited. 4 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1786 exited. 3 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1787 exited. 2 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: Core process 1777 exited. 1 remaining
Nov 28 16:33:01 EMserver1 heartbeat: [1695]: info: emserver1 Heartbeat shutdown complete.`

If I restarted heartbeat at this point... the resources heartbeat controls would start up fine.... please help!

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but if you run a recent enough version of Ubuntu then you should do yourself a favour and use Corosync and Pacemaker instead of Heartbeat. There is a [great introductory article about Pacemaker](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/ahead-pack-pacemaker-high-availability-stack?page=0,0) in Linux Journal and [Clusters from Scratch](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-crmsh/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/index.html) is a great starting point for getting Corosync and Pacemaker running.

Comment: I will definitely look into that daff, but I'm already really deep into this project.. I can't afford to scrap everything and start over.

Comment: daff... after being chewed out in the Linux-HA channel on freenode. I built up a corosync/pacemaker cluster. It's doing exactly what I want it to do. Thank you... wish I could have come up with a solid answer for this heartbeat problem! I think I needed some sort of fencing set up.

Comment: the old Heartbeat HA stack has so many conceptual shortcomings and has been obsoleted for so long now it is not even worth trying to debug the problems that are bound to arise when you use it today. Corosync and Pacemaker have been created for this exact reason and they work just so much better than Heartbeat (which isn't even a resource manager) ever could. So you did the right thing. And don't fret, you will get plenty of chances to thoroughly debug your Pacemaker setup in the future :)

Comment: daff, add your suggestion as an answer. You fixed the problem, right?

Comment: Indeed... His "suggestion" was nice enough to be considered an answer (compared to what I got in the IRC channels). It got me on the right track and I'm very impressed with pacemaker/corosync! Okay enough with the spam sorry guys! Take care!

Comment: @daff Please do as Mark and Matthew say. I'd hate for the bounty to go to waste.

Comment: Ok, I have added my comments as answer. Wouldn't mind some bounty :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commanded in the comments here is my initial suggestion in answer form.

If you run a recent enough Ubuntu version (10.04 or newer) you should ditch Heartbeat completely and use Corosync and Pacemaker instead. While this is not a answer or solution to your particular problem it will, as you have seen, make your problem simply disappear.

A [great introductory article about Pacemaker](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/ahead-pack-pacemaker-high-availability-stack?page=0,0) was written in Linux Journal and [Clusters from Scratch](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-crmsh/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/index.html) is a great starting point for getting Corosync and Pacemaker up and running. For Ubuntu 10.04 please use the PPA for the official stable backported cluster stack: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-ha-maintainers/+archive/ppa

The old Heartbeat stack has many conceptual shortcomings and has been obsoleted for so long now it is not worth trying to debug the problems that are bound to arise if you use it today. Corosync and Pacemaker have been created for this exact reason and they work just so much better than Heartbeat, which isn't even a resource manager, ever could.